# Change Clock Position at Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, clock

Is it possible to change the clock position to the right of the bar instead of the center in Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 2):

As of old, you will find extensions that allow to move the clock on the Gnome Extensions website. [Frippery Move Clock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2/move-clock/) by rmyorston  is one that is around for a long time and faithfully has been updated throughout.

Comment: I used this extension in Ubuntu 20, however, in one of the comments, it says that it is not compatible with Gnome 42, the same version of Ubuntu 22. Anyway, thanks for your recommendation!

Comment: Please consider "accepting" the answer if it resolved your issue: click the checkmark next to the question. This also shows other users in the overview that a useful answer can be found here.